# Microsoft silverlight controls not recognised by microsoft visual studio 2010 ultimate coded UI Test

Tags: silverlight, testing, user-interface, automation

Req: Need to do automation testing on Website with **silverlight controls** using **"MS Visual Studio 2010 ultimate - coded UITest"**. 
Problem: While recording silverlight control, it displays an error "MS Silverlight control cannot be recognised. Check http:\go.microsoft.com\fwlink\?linkID=157214"

how to resolve this issue with prerequiste

Answer (score 0):

Probably the IE browser should be set to Compatibility view.

http://swautomation.wordpress.com/tag/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-uitest-extension-silverlightuiautomationhelper/